# com eu faço para imprimir os múltiplos de N num intervalo na linguagem C, o meu código não roda

Tags: c#, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    int n, a, b;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &a, &b);
    for(n=a;n=n+n);
    {   printf("\n%d",n);   }

    getchar();
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int n, b, a;
int x, verificador, total;

total = 0;
```

/* primeiro valor do intervalo */

```
printf("digite o primeiro numero do intervalo\n");
scanf("%d", &a);
```

/*segundo valor do intervalo */

```
printf("digite o ultimo valor do intervalo\n");
scanf("%d", &b);
```

/*valor a ser testado dos múltiplos */

```
printf("digite o valor a testar seeh multiplo\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
```

/* x é o valor que iniciará a contagem, a vai até o valor de b (final do intervalo, onde sempre soma 1
cada vez que efetua o teste se pertence ao intervalo o laço verifica se a variavel verificador recebe o resto da divisao de x (contador) pelo multiplo,
se o resultado do verificador receber o valor 0, significa que x é divisivel por n, que é o que será executado pelo teste a seguir no if, então, se verificador é
0, será impresso na tela o valor de x, no codigo deixei comentado a variavel total, que é um contador de quantas vezes este ocorre dentro do laço, caso seja necessário */

```
for(x = a; x <= b; x = x +1)
{
    verificador = x % n;
    
    if(verificador == 0)
    {
        
        printf("%d eh multiplo de %d\n", x,n);
        //total = total + 1;
    }
    
}
```

//printf("o codigo encontrou %d resultados", total);

```
}
```

Comment: Por favor, formate o seu código para melhor visualização , no stackoverflow é utilizando a sintaxe do markdown

Comment: **obrigado** pela dica!